# why is umask for files is subtracted from 666 and not 777?

Tags: linux, permissions, umask

umask value is subtracted from 666 to set default permissions for a new file and subtracted from 777 for new directory.
to change the file permission we use chmod after its been created.
how can I create new files with 755 default permission?

Comment: No, the `umask` value is not subtracted from 666 or 777. Actually, a mask is applied by the OS by first complementing (negating) the mask, and then performing a logical AND with the requested file mode.

Answer (score 1):

The umask is subtracted from whatever the application specifies as the permissions when calling `open()` or `mkdir()`.

Generally, applications specify permissions `666` when creating a data file, or `777` when creating a directory or executable file. The applications that create executable files are generally just linkers (which may be called internally by compilers).

There's no way to use umask to add permissions, it only subtracts. Why would you want all files to be created with `755` permissions, when they can't actually be executed? Script files need executable permissions, but most data files are not scripts.

Of course, in the application you're writing you can use `777` permissions in your calls to `open()`. I assume you're programming, otherwise this question would be off-topic here, and would belong on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: suppose I want to create a script "foo.sh". by default the permissions for this file when I touch it is rw-rw-r. I want all my scripts to have permissions as 755 when i touch it. is this possible?

Comment: That's an exception. You wouldn't want a text editor to assume everything you're creating is a script.

Comment: oh. Got it. Thanks

Comment: hi @Barmar , why directories can have execute permission? why is it needed?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work